# protocol buffer header collision

Tags: protocol-buffers, header-files

I'm new to Protocol Buffers(PB). Now i need to communicate with 2 third-party service using PB. 
But it fails to work with this compiling error:

> cxs_service.pb.h: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `TSResponse' with no type
>   cxs_service.pb.h: error: invalid use of`::'

My header files include 2 3rd-party .h files looking like this:

```
#include "mob/include/ts_service.pb.h"
#include "pc/include/cxs_service.pb.h"


//### pc/include/cxs_service.pb.h ###
// The compiler seems to find ts_service.pb.h under pc/include successfully
// but it cannot recognize ::pc::TSResponse which is defined in it
# include "ts_service.pb.h"       
namespace pc {
class CXSRequest : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
    inline const ::pc::TSResponse& ts_response() const;
} // class CXSRequest 
} // namespace pc

// i've found that mob/include/ts_service.pb.h, pc/include/ts_service.pb.h have the same header guard.
// Thus pc/include/cxs_service.pb.h really found pc/include/ts_service.pb.h.
// but cannot include it's content because of exactly the same header guard.
#ifndef PROTOBUF_ts_5fservice_2eproto__INCLUDED
#define PROTOBUF_ts_5fservice_2eproto__INCLUDED
#endif
```

the first 3rd-party PB message:

```
// ts_service.proto
package mob;

message TSResponse {
    required uint64 id = 1;
}
```

the second 3rd-party PB message:

```
// cxs_service.proto
package pc;

import ts_service.proto;
message CXSRequest {
    optional TSResponse ts_response = 1;
}

// which depends on its own ts_service.proto:
// ts_service.proto
package pc;

message TSResponse {
    optional string name = 1;
}
```

Comment: it seems that the compiler can't recognize ::pc::TSResponse which defined in pc::ts_service.pb.h. The compiler find ts_service.pb.h of mob first, which defines ::mob::TSResponse.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is that there are two different `ts_service.proto` files with conflicting definitions. Normally you would solve this by putting each package's protos in a different directory, e.g. `pc/ts_service.proto` and `mob/ts_service.proto`.

Note that when using `protoc` to compile these files, you will want to set up the import path to point at the parent of these two directories; do not add each directory to the path directly as this will lead to the same conflict. That is:

```
# BAD
protoc -Isrc/pc -Isrc/mob src/pc/cxs_service.proto

# GOOD
protoc -Isrc src/pc/cxs_service.proto
```

Note that the `import` statements in each `.proto` will have to be updated to give the full path of the file being imported, i.e. `import "/pc/ts_service.proto";` instead of `import "ts_service.proto";`.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I can compile this two 3rd-party proto successfully. But when i include them in my apps, compiling error occurs